# AWS Lambda java.lang.NoClassDefFound Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, classnotfoundexception

I created java package using AWS Lambda toolkit for eclipse.
I am trying to convert object to JSON using ObjectMapper. I added jackson-all-1.9.0.jar.
Test cases using junit is working fine. But when i export java project to jar and upload it on AWS lambda and test it . Lambda gives errorjava.lang.NoClassDefFound Error.
I am not using maven or gradle to build project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a fat jar with all the dependencies.